# Bubble sorting an int array

Tags: java, beginner, sorting

I'd like to improve this bubble sort code

```
 package com.arun.sort;

 import java.util.Arrays;

 public class BubbleSort {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] arr={2,5,1,8,12,3,7};
    int n=arr.length;

    for(int k=0;k<n-1;k++){
        for(int i=0;i<n-k-1;i++){
            if(arr[i]>arr[i+1]){
                int temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[i+1];
                arr[i+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Sorted array" +Arrays.toString(arr));



  }

   }
```

Comment: I'm assuming you know this, and that the bubble sort is an exercise, but the easiest way to improve on this would be to choose anything but a bubble sort. As far as I know, there are no use-cases where the bubble sort isn't the worst performing sort algorithm.

Comment: @DominicCronin - for empty-set data, bubblesort is among the fastest ... ;-)

Comment: @rolfl :-) For an empty dataset, the "Don't sort" algorithm is even faster.

Comment: @DominicCronin: rotating drum (i.e. not random-access) storage, with suitable constraints (not sure exactly: I suppose a read head at least one record before the write head or something along those lines?), bubble sort is not only useful it's *optimal*. Whether that can still be called a "use-case" in 2014 is another matter.

Comment: Steve Jessop - interesting - got a reference?

Comment: There's a special case: A sorted array where all entries are _slightly_ changed, and then the array is sorted again. In that case bubble sort with an exit from the outer loop when the array is sorted is quite good.

Comment: @dominiccronin for an almost sorted array, bubble sort is actually very fast. Bubble sort (actually, it's faster cousin, shaker sort) is often used in the final stages of a quick sort (array is almost sorted) because the overhead from the recursion makes it simply faster to run two iterations of shaker sort over the thing. Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/159974/36120

Comment: Thanks @EmilyL. Interesting stuff. Yet even for that use case, shaker does better, and my initial bold (rash?) statement still stands! :-) (Apart from Steve Jessop's case, where bubble is used as a hardware optimization algorithm rather than a sort per se.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Step 1: format it nicely

An IDE can automatically reformat code nicely to follow the standard:

```
int n = arr.length;

for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n - k - 1; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

In Eclipse it's Control-Shift-f. It adds spaces around operators. Now the code looks like the standard, and it's easier to read and code review for everyone.

#### Step 2: extract to a method

In the current code you have a hardcoded array, and the main logic follows right after. It's hard to test this way. What if you want to see if the implementation works with a different set of numbers? You have to rewrite the array. Better to extract the main logic into its own, independent method:

```
void sort(int[] arr) {
    // ...
}
```

Now you can test with multiple different inputs easier:

```
arr = new int[]{2, 5, 1, 8, 12, 3, 7};
BubbleSort.sort(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

arr = new int[]{4, 3, 2, 1, 2};
BubbleSort.sort(arr);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

#### Step 3: convert print statements to proper unit tests

The problem with print statements is that every time you change something and rerun, you have to re-verify the output of each statement. Unit tests can automate the verification step, and converting is easy enough to do:

```
@Test
public void testMixedValues() {
    int[] arr = {2, 5, 1, 8, 12, 3, 7};
    BubbleSort.sort(arr);
    assertEquals("[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 12]", Arrays.toString(arr));
}

@Test
public void testDecreasingValues() {
    int[] arr = {4, 3, 2, 1};
    BubbleSort.sort(arr);
    assertEquals("[1, 2, 3, 4]", Arrays.toString(arr));
}

@Test
public void testDecreasingWithDups() {
    int[] arr = {4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2};
    BubbleSort.sort(arr);
    assertEquals("[1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4]", Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

Now you can make changes and the test cases will flag an error if something breaks. Unless you do something really horrible, typically only a few of the test cases will break, and you don't need to reverify the others that are still working, which makes debugging a lot easier.

#### Minor things

Instead of `n`, a better name would be `length` to cache the length of the array.

As for the loop variables, it's more traditional to name nested counter variables as `i`, `j`, `k`, in this order of nesting level, instead of `k`, `i` as you did. In any case, this is really not a big deal.

```
int length = arr.length;

for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
            int temp = arr[j];
            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer gives some really solid help for a beginner. My only quibble is using the code itself to generate assertion data. We all do it, and it's a great tip, but then you still need to verify that the generated data is correct.

Comment: @DominicCronin fair enough, I dropped that paragraph ;-)

Answer (score 10):

**API (or the lack of one):**

As it stands, we can't sort any array except the one you've hard coded into the main method. You should create a separate `bubbleSort` method that accepts an array of numbers as a parameter. Then we could *call* that method from `main`, or anywhere really.

**Naming:**

It's hard. Really hard, but I recommend against one and two letter variable names. It tends to obfuscate the code and make it hard to follow. I don't like having to map meanings in my head. That's even harder than naming things.

- `n` could be something like `initialLength` or `arrLength`.
- `i`, `j`, & `k` *are* traditionally used for loop indexes, but I don't like them in nested loops. I prefer `inner` and `outer` when lacking a better index name. If you stick with them though, the outer most loop should be `i` moving up the alphabet to `j` for the inner loop.
- `temp`? Temp what?! Try `tempValue`.

Note that the naming stuff is nitpicky, but the code structure is not. You shouldn't program right inside main like that.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with `tempValue`: it adds length to the identifier without really adding any meaning.

Comment: @Hurkyl I agree that it's not a great alternative, but I think it does clarify that the code sorts the array in place and that `temp` is a value and not a temporary array.

Comment: i, j and k are so embedded in programming culture as loop indices (ever since that's where integers began in Fortran), that it's probably OK to use them for that. I do. Still - I prefer to use i for the outermost loop, and so on.

Comment: That's a good point @DominicCronin and I mentioned that, but just because something "has always been that way" doesn't make it right or good. I will update my answer with the part about `i` being the outer most loop though.

Answer (score 8):

Let me start with the glaring issue, I want to get that done, and leave the rest to others,,

## Formatting

Your code formatting is messy. there is just three things that are not indented in a java-file as per conventions.

these three things are:

1. Package-declaration
2. Import statements
3. Class-opening and closing

Everything else is usually indented by either 4 spaces or 1 tab, **in the least!**
You nicely indented your for-loops though ;)

In addition to that, your operators and statements are a bit very cramped.
Oracle advises to and uses a few tricks to make operations more visible to the programmer:

- Arithmetic operators (+,-,*,/,<,>) have a space before and after
- Same goes for logical operators (&&,||,...)
- before opening and after closing parentheses there is a space, but not if it's respectively after or before another parenthesis.

Comment: I am not going to add a comment on the overuse of newlines here, because I feel that the other problems are more in need of help.

Answer (score 1):

In this code you can find it provides optimum solution. It compare only one time if array is already sorted , the first loop having `k` variable will run only one time. while in other answers above no one focused on that. Also you can see here second loop having `l` as integer not compare elements which are already sorted

```
/** here I am using boolean variable for case where user inputs array that 
is already sorted so in this case after performing loop operation for 1 time 
and if there will be no change in the in the boolean value means array is 
already sorted and return statement will act and we gets out of loop. 
*/

public class Bubblesort {

   public static int arr[];

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        System.out.println("Enter number of element you have in array for performing bubblesort");

        int numbofele = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        System.out.println("numer of element entered is" + "\n" + numbofele);

        arr = new int[numbofele];

        System.out.println("Enter Elements of array");

        System.out.println("The given array is");


        for (int i = 0, j = 1; i < numbofele; i++, j++) {

            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[j]);

            System.out.println(arr[i]);

        }

        boolean swapped = false;

        System.out.println("The sorted array is");

        for (int k = 0; k < numbofele - 1; k++) {


            for (int l = 0; l + 1 < numbofele - k; l++) {

                if (arr[l] > arr[l + 1]) {

                    int temp = arr[l];
                    arr[l] = arr[l + 1];
                    arr[l + 1] = temp;
                    swapped = true;

                }
            }

            if (!swapped) {

                for (int m = 0; m < numbofele; m++) {

                    System.out.println(arr[m]);
                }

                return;

            }
        }

        for (int m = 0; m < numbofele; m++) {

            System.out.println(arr[m]);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't help but notice that `swapped`  and the if-block at the end of your method are not changing the observable behaviour of the code in any way. That would be easier to notice if the code was formatted properly. AFAICT the only thing you changed is adding facilities for inputting the array elements manually as well as a useless boolean variable

Comment: vogel612 now you can see the use of boolean there. I edited code with explanation

Comment: first things first: you can make sure I see a comment by pinging me with an "@" (`@Vogel612`). Secondly: that makes more sense. Let me suggest an alternative. Instead of duplicating the output code, you could use `break`  to terminate the loop (instead of returning out of it). That feels cleaner to me (and doesn't intermingle sorting with printing). Note that this idea can be taken a step further by resetting `swapped` every time in the outer loop